# Fortran Error fmt: read unexpected error. Possible Hidden Characters?

Tags: vim, fortran

I am running a Fortran code, compiling using g77 version 3.4.0 on a Mac OSX 10.9.4.  I am running into the following error in my code:

```
    fmt: read unexpected character
    apparent state: unit 4 named P_resids_inversion
    last format: (6(I3,X,F7.2,X,I2,X))
    lately reading sequential formatted external IO
```

I understand that this error must have to do with the formatting of input that requires the (6(I3,X,F7.2,X,I2,X)) format.  I have located where this formatting is in the script, and have checked the input.  The above formatting corresponds with the following lines of sample data:

```
 27   -0.23  1  26   -0.03  1  28    0.52  1  17    1.09  1  29    0.07  1  25    0.14  1
 30    0.09  1  24   -0.13  1   4   -0.01  1  35   -0.48  1  23   -0.28  1  22   -0.08  1
 21   -0.66  1   0    0.00  0   0    0.00  0   0    0.00  0   0    0.00  0   0    0.00  0
```

I have compared this input file with another input file that does work with this Fortran code with no issues with formatting -- I've checked the spacing many times and found no discrepancies.  Here is my hypothesis for why this error is occurring, even though the spacing is correct:

I created the input file using a Perl Script, which applies a "\n" newline character once the 6th group of inputs (I3, F7.2,I2) is completed.  There may be a hidden newline character that was not removed in the input file, giving Fortran a fit.  However, I opened both of the input files in VIM and performed the ":set list" command, and the only character at the end of each line is a dollar sign.

I was wondering if you have any ideas for how to possibly remove hidden characters within my input file, or if there are any other reasons for this hiccup in the fortran code, even though the input is correct (in a text file)?

As a side note, the input file that I know works is a Unix executable file, whereas the malfunctioning input file is a text file, and the malfunctioning file was created on a Mac.

Comment: i think that format requires at least one blank at the end of each line. that said a simple list directed read should work just fine.

Comment: I thought the same way and so tried a similar test program, but I found at least gfortran seems to be able to correctly handle the case where the last blank does not exist. So I am wondering if this is a specific problem of g77? Also agree that read(4,*) ... would be much easier.

Comment: had to look it up. ( I essentially never use formatted reads.. )  I think the final `x` with nothing left to read should be ok.  I might add a space for curiosity sake, then ditch the old compiler if that is the issue.